# Laravel queue nested processes

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I want to use a queue for file uploads. Users can upload files. Each file will have around 500 rows. Now I want to implement this logic:

- Maximum of 5 files can be processed at the same time. The remaining files should be in the queue.
- Each file should have 5 processes, so 5 rows will be inserted into databases at the same time. Shortly, there are will be a maximum of 25
  processes (5 processes in every 5 files).

Now I am adding all files to one queue. Files processing one by one. Shortly first-come, first out. 2nd file needs to wait to finish 1st file.

How can I implement this? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is the difference between processing a file, and inserting rows into the DB?

If you want to run multiple workers for the same queue, you can simply start more workers using `php artisan queue:work` and additionally use flags to specify the queues `--queue=process-files` for example. See [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#running-multiple-queue-workers).

In a production environment, consider to [configure a supervisor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#configuring-supervisor) to run a specific amount of workers on a queue using `numprocs` directive.

Do I understand correctly you want to run 25 queue workers per user? That does not seem right. Instead, you should consider creating queues for fast/slow jobs.